# UTF8 byte[] to string conversion

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, type-conversion

I have UTF8 `byte[]` of infinite size (i.e. of very large size). I want to truncate it to `1024` bytes only and then convert it to string.

`Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[], int, int)` does that for me. It first shortens `1024` bytes and then gives me its converted string.

But in this conversion, if last character is of UTF8 character set, which is made of 2 bytes and whose first byte falls in range and another byte is out of range then it displays `?` for that character in converted string.

Is there any way so that this `?` does not come in converted string?

Answer (score 6):

That's what the `Decoder` class is for. It allows you to stream `byte` data into `char` data, while maintaining enough state to handle partial code-points correctly:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder().GetChars(buffer, 0, 1024, charBuffer, 0)
```

Of course, when the code-point is split in the middle, the `Decoder` is left with a "partial char" in its state, but that doesn't concern you in your case (and is desirable in all the other use cases :)).

Comment: I don't known how to deal with pointers. Any help or alternative of your solution?

Comment: @pratik03 No pointers involved - just use the `char[]` (and `byte[]`) overload instead of the `char*` (and `byte*`) overload.